# Entity Framework Maintaining Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a Single Location Table that has multiple foreign key relationships in it. It has foreign keys to a state table, a city table, a country table, and a user table. Now I have the table model mapped properly in the Entity framework, but if I try to access the foreign key id field in the Location table to add a new foreign key mapping I cannot access it, instead I get a Reference field, such as **StateReference**.

Now I have found some articles saying, just use the entitykey.StateReference. I tried it and it works but seems really clunky to me. What I have noticed though is it also supplies me with a field State instead of StateID. So, from that I am assuming that one would just be able to pass in the state name to the Location object and entity framework would figure the relationship out almost automatically. I am not able to locate or figure out the proper syntax for this anywhere.

If I am way off base here could someone please point in the right direction and correct me? I have been pounding at this for awhile and cannot seem to get it. Or if What I am saying is correct can someone give me some basic code to display the syntax. I am making a web service in VS2010 so I am using ef v1 if I understand correctly. Below is the Code for my Location Object.

```
    using(Entities context = new Entities())
     {
       Location NewLocation = new Location
        {
          //In SQL all three of these field are acutally foreign key ids I am 
             trying to maintian
          State = context.States.Where(i => i.State1.Equals(AddedState)),
          Country = context.Countries.Where(i => i.State1.Equals(AddedCountry)),
          City = context.Cities.Where(i => i.City1.Equals(AddedCity)),
         }
      };
      context.AddToLocation(NewLocation);
      context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Comment: You'll want to read a little about the editor here at SO (click Help then Advanced help in the question editor). Don't use leading spaces for your paragraphs, that turns them into code blocks. I edited it but it will take some time for my edits to get through the approval process. Per your question, I know in EF 4.x I was able to set an option telling it to map the foreign keys as well as creating the references. I don't think this option was available in prior versions so you might also specify which EF version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be:

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
{
    Location NewLocation = new Location
    {
      State = context.States.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == AddedState.ID),
      Country = context.Countries.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == AddedCountry.ID),
      City = context.Cities.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == AddedCity.ID)
    };
    context.AddToLocation(NewLocation);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

(assuming that the primary key properties are called `ID`)

BTW: Using VS2010 does not necessarily mean that you are using EF Version 1. Important is the .NET Framework target platform of your project: If the project targets .NET 3.5 you are using EF Version 1. If the project targets .NET 4.0 you are using EF Version 4. (Version 2 and 3 don't exist.) The default target platform when you create a new project in VS2010 is .NET 4.0. So, it's more likely that you use EF 4.0 unless you explicitly changed the target platform to .NET 3.5 (or have migrated an older project from VS2008 for example to VS2010).

As mentioned by Tod in the comment below your question, with EF 4.0 you have the option to expose the foreign key columns as model properties when you create/update the model from an existing database schema. In the Update Wizard is a check box "*Include foreign key columns in the model*":

[image: Update Wizard]

**Edit**

If `AddedState`, `AddedCountry` and `AddedCity` are strings that represent the `Name` property of the entities, you can just replace the query by `ID` by a query by `Name`:

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
{
    Location NewLocation = new Location
    {
      State = context.States.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == AddedState),
      Country = context.Countries.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == AddedCountry),
      City = context.Cities.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == AddedCity)
    };
    context.AddToLocation(NewLocation);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that the use of `SingleOrDefault` assumes that the `Name` is unique in the database tables. If there are two or more records with the same name `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception ("sequence contains more than one element"). You can replace `SingleOrDefault` by `FirstOrDefault` then to just load the first record with the given name.

Comment: I guess I do not follow because AddedState is a string of the state to be added into the database. So is this implying that I have to go and retrieve the id of the added state and then use my single or default to then go back to the table again and retrieve the id to set it to the state foreign key id in my Location table? If I am understanding that correctly that seems super redundant. I think I am miss interpreting something here so if you could please explain a little more. Also I am using v 3.5 so EF 1.

Comment: @user1474882: No, you don't need to load the ID. You need to load the entity itself by any query. That doesn't need to be a query by ID, you can just use a query by name. See my Edit section above.